# Using split() function on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

I'm trying to get rid of the percentage signs. In order to do this I decided to apply a function to the Democrat and Republican column and try to split() by the percentage sign. The following code tries to do that:

```
gallup_2012[['Democrat/Lean Democratic', 'Republican/Lean 
Republican']].apply(lambda x: x.split('%')[0])
```

However, when I try to do this, I get the following error:

> ("'Series' object has no attribute 'split'", u'occurred at index Democrat/Lean > Democratic')

I'm not quite sure why this error occurs, as I can apply other functions to this series. It's just that the split() function doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`df[[ ]]` returns a dataframe, so if you use `df.apply()` then it would be applied on `pd.Series`. And `Series` doesn't have `split()` method, But if you use `df[ ]` and use `df.apply()` then you would be able to achieve what you want. The drawback is only that you can apply only on one column.

```
gallup_2012['Democrat/Lean Democratic'].apply(lambda x: x.split('%')[0])
```

Comment: How come when I do an operation like apply(lambda x: x+'s') this still works on every individual element even if I'm applying it to a dataframe?

Comment: see the output of `df.apply(lambda x : type(x)` and `df['column'].apply(lambda x : type(x))`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) method on the desired columns

```
df["column"] = df["column"].str.replace("%", "")
```

Comment: Yeah I could, although I'm curious as to why the other method doesn't work

Comment: This doesn't work in pandas 0.25  AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!